# javascript how to display text when mouse over input text box?

Tags: javascript, text, input

How to display text when mouse over an input text box the simplest way (no css, or etc)??

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Put some title and alt attributes on it.

```
<input type="text" title="show this text" alt="show this text" />
```

Comment: Using a title attribute for that is however bad practise, the title attribute is the title of the element, nothing more.

Browsers are not required to display it when you hover over it, and using it as such could be argued to be considered back practise.

Comment: so what do you suggest Lajla?

Answer (score 3):

Don't have to use the alt attribute just the title will do this for you.

Answer (score 0):

editbox.title = "XXX";